# On WebSphere, JNDI lookup fails during CDI container bootstrap

Tags: websphere, cdi, jndi, websphere-9

On WebSphere 9, I'm trying to do a JNDI lookup from a CDI extension and I get this error:

```
javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component...
```

So, there is application code (inside an EAR) executed by a server-managed thread, on a JavaEE component lifecycle callback but there is no bounded JNDI context.

I've played with `com.ibm.ws.cdi.immediate.ejb.start` system property to see if this helps but I had no luck.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately JNDI lookups cannot be performed inside a CDI extension as Websphere triggers the observers in CDI extensions before the JNDI namespace is configured.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: No worries :P . I wanna say this is a WAS bug... don't you agree?